# boost::this_thread::sleep_for can hang when using pthreads and system time rolling backwards

Tags: c++, boost, pthreads

When I calling (on linux) `boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(50))` and rolling system time back for 10 seconds, execution of sleep_for takes 10.05 seconds instead of 0.05.

I have checked, that `usleep(50000)` and `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50))` does not cause this problem.

I have checked on Windows, that `boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(50))` does not cause this problem.

Actual boost code:

```
    // Use pthread_delay_np or nanosleep whenever possible here in the no_interruption_point
    // namespace because they do not provide an interruption point.
    #   if defined(BOOST_HAS_PTHREAD_DELAY_NP)
    #     if defined(__IBMCPP__) ||  defined(_AIX)
                  BOOST_VERIFY(!pthread_delay_np(const_cast<timespec*>(&ts.getTs())));
    #     else
                  BOOST_VERIFY(!pthread_delay_np(&ts.getTs()));
    #     endif
    #   elif defined(BOOST_HAS_NANOSLEEP)
                  nanosleep(&ts.getTs(), 0);
    #   else
                  // This should never be reached due to BOOST_THREAD_SLEEP_FOR_IS_STEADY
    # endif
```

As we can see, if `BOOST_HAS_PTHREAD_DELAY_NP` defined (and it is defined on all my linux PCs including libboost from Debian repositories), boost calling for `pthread_delay_np()`.

From description of pthread_delay_np looks like it should hang when we rolling time back:

> This routine causes a thread to delay execution for a specific interval of
>     time. This interval ends at the current time plus the specified interval.
>     The routine will not return before the end of the interval is reached

But description of boost sleep_for looks like it is steady clock:

> Suspends the current thread until the duration specified by rel_time has elapsed.

I expect, that `sleep_for` is steady clock. 
Is it boost problem, or I should recompile boost without `BOOST_HAS_PTHREAD_DELAY_NP`?

Comment: When it comes to `std::this_thread::sleep_for` it seems like it's implementation defined but: "_The standard recommends that a steady clock is used to measure the duration. If an implementation uses a system clock instead, the wait time may also be sensitive to clock adjustments._"

So, try the standard one and see if there's a difference.

Comment: @TedLyngmo as i wrote, I have checked - ```std::this_thread::sleep_for``` is steady clock on my system.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Then it certainly looks like a boost problem. Are there any reasons for sticking with `boost::this_thread::sleep_for`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo in out projects we use prefer to boost over std because of std is much more realization specific with msvc/gcc/etc. In this case, I think, the simplest solution is to use std. I can't believe, that there is a bug in boost - mostly looks like that is a feature, that I don't understand.

Comment: I see. I usually promote using the standardized versions of the boost libraries when possible. :)